# Women's prayer books in Yiddish/English

Tags: product-recommendation, women, yiddish

Does anyone know of a good siddur/prayer book designed for women that is in Yiddish and English?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, faigy. I'm curious - what is a "women's" prayer book? I gather that prayer books are unspecific to any gender.

Comment: @DanF I suppose you're wrong: https://www.encyclopedia.com/environment/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/tekhines

Comment: _Techines_ were the traditional form of prayers in Yiddish for women in the Ashkenazi world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkhine

Comment: @Kazibácsi I learned something. I knew that many women recite Tehillim, but I didn't know that there was a formally organized set of tefillot for women.

Comment: @DanF There's a distinct type for that, _Weiberteutsch_

Comment: I never heard of one with both Yiddish and English. Do you mean "or"?